# javafx - how to get reference to main Stage in MainController in initialize() method?

Tags: javafx, initialization, stage

I need to get reference to main Stage of app in initialize() method in MainController. I tried using this solution:

```
    ...
@FXML private Label label;
...
// in some method block
Stage stageTheLabelBelongs = (Stage) label.getScene().getWindow();
```

but other label (or other controlls) doesn't exist when application call initialize() and it returns NullPointerException. How to avoid this?
Greetings

Comment: The `label` is not actually in a window at that point (and probably not even added to a scene). What do you want to do with the window here?

Comment: Its example only which i placed here to simplify situation, but idea is same. I have following code: https://scr.hu/zJjoWK This code is placed in method, which is call in initialize(). When i try get reference to main Stage (code in comments) it returns NullPointerException, beacuse contentPaneController.getVideoWebView().getScene().getWindow(); doesn't exist yet. And i want to avoid this situation. I need main Stage to place new window in correct place (code in comments too).

Comment: As I said, `initialize()` is necessarily invoked *before* the controls are placed in a scene; so in your code example `label.getScene()` *must* return null. The only way to "avoid this situation" is not to call those methods there... So, what are you actually trying to do? There is probably another way to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to place new window in the middle of main Window of app, regardless of the position main Window on screen (code in comments defines it).